# Error When trying the urldownloadtofile function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Getting error when using urldownloadtofile the error is : undefined reference to `URLDownloadToFileA'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    string dwnld_URL = "http://www.412312myfuptoload.com/downloadpage/Honeygain.exe";
    string savepath = "C:\\Users\\Ester\\Appdata\\Roaming\\Honeygain.exe";
    URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")` works with MSVC (or compatible) compiler.

From the error and your [previous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JLU0.png) question it seems you are using MinGW (ld linker) instead, which doesn't support it.

So you should link with the `-lurlmon` option.